# How could I optimize full-text search via Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

On our project we're using Elasticsearch v. 5.6.12 with [that](https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-analysis-morphology) morphological analysis plugin.

At some use-case we want to perform full-text search via multi-matching text, edge and ngram. We noticed that current realization of this request is being executed pretty slow for our prod data. Therefore, we would like it to be optimized.

Currently, our actual request looks like this:

```
  "multi_match": {
    "query": "some text",
    "fields": [
      "text^1.0",
      "text.edge^1.0",
      "text.ngram^1.0"
    ],
    "type": "best_fields",
    "operator": "AND",
    "slop": 0,
    "prefix_length": 0,
    "max_expansions": 50,
    "lenient": false,
    "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
    "boost": 1
  }
```

The root problem, as I see it, is that for every single entry we're executing comparison with "text" AND "text.edge" AND "text.ngram", meanwhile we actually may stop calculation if matching ngram returned false. But how could I say Elastic to get rid of extra work?

Under the hood out multi-match request is being transformed into something like that (as Elastic [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) says):

```
    "dis_max": {
      "queries": [
        { "match": { "text^1.0": "some text" }},
        { "match": { "text.edge^1.0": "some text" }},
        { "match": { "text.ngram^1.0": "some text" }}
      ]
    }
```

Maybe I could build dis_max request in some more flexible way instead of configuring multi_match?

Comment: Just curious, but is the reason why you're still on 5.6 because of that plugin which is not supported anymore? Running on 5.6 is a risk as that version is EOL and not supported anymore.